# Async Image Loading Performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am loading images in **UITableViewCell** receiving from url  using below code, everything is working fine but the image load very slow in **UITableViewCell** and if i think as a user, it is not acceptable.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [checkData count];
}    

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger i =indexPath.row;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView propertyImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
 NSString *test = [[checkData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"image"];
    CGRect frame=propertyImage.bounds;
    AsyncImageView asyImage=[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [asyImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]];
    self.urlForTesting=[NSURL URLWithString:test];
    [asyImage loadImageFromURL:self.urlForTesting];
    asyImage.imageURL =self.urlForTesting;
    asyImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    asyImage.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    [propertyImage addSubview:asyImage];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: try the following it is easy to handle 

  [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), 

  [Asynchronous-Freeloader](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Asynchronous-Freeloader), 
 
  [Asynchronous image loading](http://cocoanuts.mobi/2014/04/27/fastscroll/)

Comment: try this solution from apple developer library :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Use AFNetworking Class & add additional two file to download from github **"UIImageView+AFNetworking"** and import in your project. then after add this code from **"cellForRowAtIndexPath"**

```
// Fetch Image from URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[checkData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"image"]];
[objWinner.actWinner startAnimating];
[objWinner.actWinner setHidden:NO];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[objWinner.imgwinner setImageWithURLRequest:req placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
     [objWinner.actWinner stopAnimating]; // this is Activityindicator
     [objWinner.actWinner setHidden:YES];
     objWinner.imgwinner.image = image;
   } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
}];
```

Comment: can u provide the downloading link?

Comment: You could also consider caching using `UIImageView+AFNetworking`. see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31937376/1835803

Comment: it's custom class object name